from engine.command import speak ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'
[Running] python -u "e:\New folder\jarvis\engine\features.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\New folder\jarvis\engine\features.py", line 5, in 
from engine.command import speak
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'
[Done] exited with code=1 in 10.829 seconds
[Running] python -u "e:\New folder\jarvis\engine\features.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\New folder\jarvis\engine\features.py", line 5, in 
from engine.command import speak
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'engine'

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If I understood the question, you are importing the parent folder of the "importer". Try from command import speak.
